# How to use promises in the case below

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and want to use ngtasty serverside pagination but I am getting some issue like this

I have initialize method which call getMetaData function which make API call and set the `$scope.publishersModel = [];` and other model on basis of api data

```
$scope.initialize = function () {
  $scope.publishersModel = [];
  $scope.sitesModel = [];
  $scope.getMetaData();
};
```

Also for getting data which is shown in table I have `getData(selectedPublishers,selectedSites)` function which takes the selected models as parameter and this function retrun the data like this

```
{ "header": [{"Date" :"Date"}, {"Site":"Site"}],
  "rows":[{"Publisher_Name":"FashionDivaDesign","Site":"FashionDivaDesign.com","Date":"2015-12-06",}],
  "pagination": {"size":668,"pages":"67","count":10}
}
```

but currently parameters i.e. getData(param) are not available which set after success of api call of getMetaData()

So any idea how I can manage this data dependency

Comment: I will create jsFiddle and provide soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to encapsulate this in a `service` but you can try something like:

```
$scope.getMetaData().then(function(data){
    return getData(data.selectedPublishers,data.selectedSites)
})
.then(function(data){
    $scope.something = data.rows;  
});
```

If you provide a jsFiddle/Plunker/CodePen, the answer can be more precise...

Comment: but I have used `bind-resource-callback="getTableData"` which calls `getData(param, page, count)`

Comment: sounds like controller duties are creeping into your html... :)